# Cannot save attributes and render on page custom block

Tags: wordpress, block, wordpress-gutenberg

A new custom block I created, it is visible in the block list and renders correctly on the edit page, but when saved, it is not rendered on the home page.

functions.php

```
<?php

require 'inc/autoload.php';

require 'inc/theme-functions.php';
require 'inc/gutenberg-blocks.php';
```

gutenberg-blocks.php

```
function registerExtensionCategory($categories): array
{
    $result = [
        [
            'slug'  => 'extension-blocks',
            'title' => 'Blocks category name'
        ]
    ];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $result[] = $category;
    }
    return $result;
}

function misanGutenbergBlocks(): void
{
    $version = wp_get_theme()->get('Version');
    //load styles
    wp_enqueue_style('misan-custom-blocks', get_template_directory_uri() . '/misan_blocks.css', [], $version);

    //load fontawesome
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css');

    // load blocks js
    wp_enqueue_script('misan-custom-blocks', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/blocks.js', ['wp-blocks', 'wp-editor', 'wp-components', 'wp-element'], $version);

    //register blocks
    register_block_type('misan-custom-blocks/paragraph-with-title', [
        'editor-script' => 'paragraph-with-title'
    ]);
    register_block_type('misan-custom-blocks/company-numbers', [
        'editor-script' => 'company-numbers'
    ]);
    register_block_type('misan-custom-blocks/opinions', [
        'editor-script' => 'opinions'
    ]);
    register_block_type('misan-custom-blocks/contact-form', [
        'editor-script' => 'contact-form'
    ]);
    register_block_type('misan-custom-blocks/image-with-text', [
        'editor-script' => 'image-with-text'
    ]);
    register_block_type('misan-custom-blocks/offers', [
        'editor-script' => 'offers'
    ]);
    register_block_type('misan-custom-blocks/price-list', [
        'editor-script' => 'price-list'
    ]);
}

add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'misanGutenbergBlocks');
add_filter('block_categories_all', 'registerExtensionCategory');
```

proceList.js

```
const {registerBlockType} = wp.blocks;

registerBlockType('misan-custom-blocks/price-list', {
    title: 'Price list',
    icon: 'list-view',
    category: 'extension-blocks',
    edit: ({attributes, setAttributes}) => {
        return ([
            <section id={'price'}>
                <p>test</p>
            </section>
        ]);
    },
    save: ({attributes}) => {
        return ([
            <section id={'price'}>
                <p>test</p>
            </section>
        ]);
    }
});
```

Only last two blocks (offers and price-list) not works others works as expected.

I've tried moving the blocks registration to other functions, but it doesn't work.
No errors in the console and server logs

Comment: I solved my problem. I imported the edit and save functions from other files, eliminated all imports in this component and it started working. Interesting, because in another component imports work properly, maybe it's about the names of the returned functions?

Comment: Possibly sounds like a browser caching issue as to why it worked the next time. As you've found a solution to your issue, you can add your solution as an answer to this question to help others who encounter a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, but I still don't know why it doesn't work the way I wanted it to.
I tried to do as follows:

price-list.js

```
import {metadata, name, price} from "./price-list/single-price.js";
import savePrice from "./price-list/save-price-list.js";
import editPrice from "./price-list/edit-price-list.js";

const {registerBlockType} = wp.blocks;

registerBlockType('misan-custom-blocks/price-list', {
    title: 'Price list',
    icon: 'list-view',
    category: 'extension-blocks',
    edit: () => editPrice(),
    save: () => savePrice()
});

registerBlockType({name, ...metadata}, price);
```

savePrice and edit Price returns simple HTML with text -> it not works for me

I moved all the code from the "savePrice" and "editPrice" functions to this file and got rid of the "imports". Now it works as it should.

price-list.js

```
const {registerBlockType} = wp.blocks;

registerBlockType('misan-custom-blocks/price-list', {
    title: 'Price list',
    icon: 'list-view',
    category: 'extension-blocks',
    edit: () => {
        return ([
            <section className={'section-inner'} id={'price-mobile'}>
                <div className={'prices'}>
                    <p>test</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        ])
    },
    save: () => {
        return (
            <section className={'section-inner'} id={'price-mobile'}>
                <div className={'prices'}>
                    <p>test</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
});
```